# Convert list of integers to strings

Tags: python, string

I need to remove files from all the /etc/rc*.d/ directories.  I can't figure out how to convert integers to strings in an list.

```
RC = ["3","4","5"]
for RCS in str(RC):
    if (os.path.exists("/etc/rc"+RC+".d/file")):
       os.remove("/etc/rc"+RC+".d/file")
    else:
       print "/etc/rc"+str(RC)+".d/file is not a file"
```

This give me: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects.  Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: There seems to be typo in your code, it should be RCS inside the loop, RC is a list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo.  In your loop, isn't it supposed to be `RCS`?  You have `RC`

Comment: `"/etc/rc"+RC` will attempt to concatenate the string to the list `RC = ["3","4","5"]`. Also, I'm not sure what integers you're trying to convert to strings. `RC` contains only strings.

Comment: Anyway, `for RCS in str(RC)` will iterate over each character of the string representation of the list, namely, `"['3', '4', '5']"`, so even concatenating `RCS` wouldn't work

Comment: Unreal, I missed the typo after two hours of troubleshooting.  I changed it to: for RCS in RC: and removed all the str entries and it worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of RC are already strings, so :

```
RC = ["3","4","5"]
for RCS in RC:
    if (os.path.exists("/etc/rc" + RCS + ".d/file")):
        os.remove("/etc/rc" + RCS + ".d/file")
    else:
        print "/etc/rc"+ RCS +".d/file is not a file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is in string format. Maybe you meant [3,4,5]. You cannot use str or int or float functions on a list. You need to use the map function to convert a list to string. In your example, the problem is str(RC). If your list is integer try this:

```
RC = [3,4,5]
for RCS in map(str, RC):
    if (os.path.exists("/etc/rc"+RCS +".d/file")):
        os.remove("/etc/rc"+RCS +".d/file")
    else:
        print "/etc/rc"+RCS +".d/file is not a file"
```

or you can use str() for each element of your list.

```
for RCS in RC:
if (os.path.exists("/etc/rc"+str(RCS) +".d/file")):
    os.remove("/etc/rc"+str(RCS) +".d/file")
else:
    print "/etc/rc"+str(RCS) +".d/file is not a file"
```